# Excel Addin; Onaction Macro Link

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've created an excel addin. It creates a sheet with prices, and includes a refresh button. The button has a macro assigned to it which calls a sub called RefreshPrices in the addin. Following is the code:

Shape.OnAction = "'BibiAddin.xlam'!RefreshPrices"

It works perfectly on the same machine, but when it is accessed from a different machine (the files are usually stored on networks), Excel throws an error that the macro cannot be found. All the other machines have the addin installed.

On the original machine, the macro assigned only contains the sub's name.
On secondary machines, the macro name contains the full path, using Drive letters, not the absolute path.

I changed the drive letters on all the computers to have the exact same letter Z:/ for the path where the addin is stored. But still the same error is happening.

Anyone faced this issue before?

Thank you

Comment: Are you running the code that creates the sheet and button on the other machines, or are they using the same sheet that was created on your machine?

Comment: Hi Rory, No the error occurs only when a sheet is originally created by another machine. The original code creating the new sheet works perfectly on all machines, and the same machine can refresh without problem.

Comment: Do the other machines have the add-in installed as a local copy, rather than accessing a copy on a network share?

Comment: Hi again, no all the machines are using a copy saved on the network. No local copies of the addin are made.

Comment: Have you tried amending the `OnAction` statement to use the full file path, in the master copy of your spreadsheet? Example: `Shape.OnAction = 'z:\yourPath\yourAddin.xlam'!yourMacro`.

Comment: I tried, but now the refresh button will not even work on the original machine anymore. I used the following: OnAction = "'Z:\Excel Addin\BibiAddin.xlam'!RefreshPrices"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I found the solution...
At the time i installed the addin on the computers, they did not all have the same drive letter. After i changed the drive letters on every computer for the location of the addin, to make them all match, the addin was still not using the new path. I had to uninstall the addin and install it again for it to work.